# Сохранение состояния фильтра? В cookies?

Tags: javascript, mysql

Добрый вечер.
Помогите советом, как обычно решаются такие дела?

Есть пользователи, у всех в базе прописаны город, регион, страна.  
 Также на сайте есть фильтр, где можно отфильтровать людей либо по городу/либо по региону/либо по стране, а также 'всемирно'.
т.е. например нам нужно посмотреть на людей из Москвы, выбираем фильтр - 'город', вбиваем Москва - получаем людей именно из Москвы.

Теперь вопрос: как сохранить состояние фильтра? Чтобы при следующем заходе на сайт выбор людей оставался по городам, и именно по Москве.

Самое нормальное что мне пришло в голову это использовать куки, вот так:
как только выбираем, допустим, город 'Москва', в куки записывается

```
ci,Москва  //где ci - "city" идентификатор того что ищем мы по городу
            также есть состояния "co" - country, 'r' - region
```

При следующем заходе на сайт смотрим существуют ли куки, и если есть - читаем состояние, в нашем случае "ci" и ищем по городам Москвичей. если же выбрали другой фильтр, например решили искать по странам, куки меняются например на

```
co,Украина  //теперь фильтровать будем по странам и выводить только Украину
```

Если же куки нету, или ее удалили - не используем фильтры, выдаём людей "worldwide".

Нормальный такой подход или может есть какие-то идеи получше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно куки. А можно механизм сессий на бэкэнде (что, в принципе, тоже через куки) - при смене фильтра делаем запрос (у вас ведь Ajax?), который изменяет соответствующую переменную сессии.